# selecting dom elements after html was inserted in a page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I created an ajax tab navigation with html being inserted into the page. the code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'main/ajaxjson/load_course_details',
        data: {page : which, course_id: id},
        success: function(home){

            $('#ajax-content ').hide();
            $('#ajax-content').empty().append(home);
            $('#ajax-content').fadeIn(); 
        }

    });
```

ok...so I append my markup into my html. Now I need to select dom elements from the inserted html, but I can not. I have the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="light-button">Next</a>
<select id="chapters-select">
    <?php foreach ($chapters as $chapter) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $chapter->id; ?>"><?php echo $chapter->title; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Here I generate the select options dynamically. When I try to do this:

```
$('#chapters-select').change(function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

it doesn't work.
How can I use javascript after I append the html via ajax ?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fyg6m/ Where are you binding the event handler?

Comment: @FelixKling. He wrote he's adding the content with `ajax` so it's must be a delegate event issue.

Comment: @gdoron: Probably, but that would imply that the elements are selected *before* they have been inserted via Ajax, which is contrary to the title. Nevertheless, I agree with you.

Comment: Why are you opening, and closing the PHP engine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use delegate event like `on` for version 1.7+

```
$('body').on('change', '#chapters-select', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

To increase performance instead of `body` you should write the closest static(Not added dynamic with ajax or javascript) element that holds "`chapters-select`

If you are using older version of `jQuery` choose the appropriate method with the following table:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+  
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+  
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` [docs:](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Comment: Or just rebind the event handler in the callback for `$.ajax`.

Comment: thank you. it is working. i don't understand why it wasn't working before, but i will research it

Comment: @Treffynnon. usually It's best practice to do things once and in one place only.

Comment: @Mythriel. Read the docs I added and referenced, It should answer all your questions and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Run this once, after the page's first load.

```
$("body").delegate('#chapters-select','change', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

It's equivalent to @gdoron's answer, but is compatible with versions of jQuery older than 1.7

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.** ( Using **ajaxStop** )

- Declare a global variable `var element;`
- Run below code inside ajax success method

  ```
  $(document).ajaxStop( function () {
       element = $('#ajax-element');
       element.css('border','1px solid red')
  });
  ```
- Now we can manipulate the element globally from anywhere using any event

  ```
  $('body').click(function (e) { 
       element.css('background','seagreen');
  });
  ```

**Method 2.** ( Using **mouseover** )

- Run below code inside ajax success method.
- Sets ajax loaded element with 2px border.

  ```
   var flag = true;  // Flag just to run the code once
   $(document).on('mouseover', function () {
      var elem = $(document).find('#ajax-element');
      if(flag == true) {
         elem.css('border','2px solid red');
         flag = false;
      }
   });
  ```

  Use `$(document).find('#ajax-element');` to find & select your element.
- `$(document).ajaxStop(function() { });` -- *Works but event runs ajax twice sometimes. Can be usefull in some cases.*
- `$(document).on('mouseenter',function(){ });` -- *Works but have to move your mouse after ajax call.*
- `$("body").delegate("selector","click",function(){});` -- *Works but requires click event after ajax call.*
- `$(document).on('change','#ajax-element',function(){});` -- *Didn't work for me.*
- `$('#ajax-element').change(function(){});` -- *Doesn't work*.
- `$('#ajax-element').click(function(){});` -- *Doesn't work.*