# Grails remoteLink ajax issue populating JQuery accordion

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, grails, grails-2.0

Following the simple example from Jquery: [Accordion Example](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)

Using a `remoteLink` function from grails (**AJAX**) the information is pulled back from the controller and sent back to the GSP, which works fine. I do however want this data to be placed within a Accordion container... click here for [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/pi3z) of current functionality.

(Event Create Page rendering form template) _form  -  GSP:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="event"  action="showContacts" method="GET" update="divContactList">Show Contacts!</g:remoteLink>

<div id="divContactList">
     <g:render template="contactListAjax" model="[contactList: contactList]" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("Checking if I'm ready :)");

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        header: 'h3',
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
```

_contactListAjax  -  GSP Template

```
<div id="accordion">
<g:each in="${contactList}" status = "i" var="contact">
    <h3>${contact.contactForename}</h3>
    <div><p>${contact.email}</p></div>
</g:each>
</div>
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, as I'm encasing the data with the div with an id accordion, yet doesn't load. Please refer to screenshot link above to see what is currently happening.

**UPDATE**

Event (Standard Generated CRUD, only showing where the relivant imports are) create - GSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery.ui.accordion.css')}"/>
<g:javascript src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></g:javascript>
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui.min.js"></g:javascript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this... (*well Hack & Slash for now... not the best, but only viable solution for now*)

`var whatever` is the stored HTML generated by the AJAX and placed into the `divContactList` on the `update function`. The Accordion is deleted and then rebuilt (*not the best approach I realise*)

```
var whatever = $('#divContactList').html();

$('#accordion').append(whatever)
         .accordion('destroy').accordion({
             collapsible: true,
             active: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
})
```

with

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true
});
```

Edit:

You can't use an `<r:script />` tag after the request is finished. The server has already laid out all of the resources. Change it to a standard javascript tag. Also the inclusion of your javascript and css files should be elsewhere on the page.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work, thanks anyhow. There has to be a deeper reason ...

Comment: I have changed as you said James, I've tried to put the JS & CSS includes in the Event - GSP and changed the <r: tag... I had done this before when trying different combinations still doesn't work I'm afraid

Comment: So the data gets rendered, but it doesnt get the accordian. Have you checked your javascript console for errors there?

Comment: Yeah I've checked, it loads the JS get 200 response ... I've just done a separate test to see if it would just load the accordion without using the ajax functionality above... and it doesn't load it so I'm just going to quickly create a separate project to see if its something within clashing or causing other problems. Thanks again for the assistance James

Comment: [Screenshot with static test data](http://d.pr/i/GzTH). The screenshot here @James is filled with some static data on the `_form.gsp` page and works fine.

I don't think this is working as the div with the id of `<div id="accordion">` is not rendered when the script is looking for that div to set up the accordion table

Do you have any thoughts on this please? I have completely run out of things to try

Comment: [Would it be something related to this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466241/selecting-dom-elements-after-html-was-inserted-in-a-page-with-ajax)