# Function not working after DOM modification via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem I can't solve by myself:

I have a function, `getPerimetre()` which is supposed to return all the element's id with the class `.perimetre`

```
var getPerimetre = function () {
   var perimetre = [];
   $(".perimetre").each(function() {
       perimetre.push($(this).attr("id"));
   });
   return perimetre;
};
```

Problem is I want to execute this function after an AJAX call which fills my container `#prevision_form`.

```
var updateForm = function () {
   var data = getData();

    var form_request = $.ajax({
            url: "lcl-flux-prevision_modification_form.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data
    });
    form_request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); });
    form_request.done(function(html) { $("#prevision_form").html(html); });
};
```

So, my code gives something -synthetized- like this:

```
updateForm();
if(!$._data($("#saveRecord")[0], "events")) {
   $j("#saveRecord").bind("click", function() {
      alert(getPerimetre());
   });
}
```

When I click my button `#saveRecord`, the alert is empty.
If I put call to my function `getPerimetre()` **before** the AJAX call, it works correctly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the `.perimetre` elements inside the `#prevision_form` element ? If so, they get overwritten..

Comment: Yes they are, and that's probably my problem. Is there a way to get them ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery doesn't work after ajax loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-ajax-loads)

Comment: Hm, actually may have misunderstood the question initially... Just to clarify: The click event handler on the button still works, but the response from the `perimetre` function isn't what you'd expect it to be? Where is that `updateForm(); ...` block of code called?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "lcl-flux-prevision_modification_form.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            // Call your function here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,That because your ajax take time (asynchronously )mean while getPerimetre() function get executed so use async.

```
 var form_request = $.ajax({
        url: "lcl-flux-prevision_modification_form.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        async :false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use on in place of bind example

```
  $(document).on("click","#saveRecord",function(){
   ....
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
var updateForm = function () {
var data = getData();

var form_request = $.ajax({
        url: "lcl-flux-prevision_modification_form.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            updateForm();
            if(!$._data($("#saveRecord")[0], "events")) {
               $j("#saveRecord").bind("click", function() {
                  alert(getPerimetre());
               });
            }
        }
});
form_request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); });
form_request.done(function(html) { $("#prevision_form").html(html); });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `.perimetre` elements in the updated html, you will need to access them after the ajax call is completed.

Since you want to do that from a `click` on another element you will have to check if the ajax is complete.

You can use the `$.active` for that (*which stores the number of active ajax calls*).

Something like

```
   $j("#saveRecord").bind("click", function() {
      if (!$.active){
         alert(getPerimetre());
      } else {
         // notify user that the data is not yet available..
         // or something else..
         alert('AJAX call in progress..');
      }
   });
```

---

**original answer**

The issue is with

```
form_request.done(function(html) { $("#prevision_form").html(html); });
```

which overwrites the contents of the `#prevision_form` element.

If you want to get the `.perimetre` elements before they get overwritten you need to access them earlier..

```
var perimetreIds = [];

var getPerimetre = function () {...}
var updateForm = function () {
    ...
    form_request.done(function(html) { 
        perimetreIds = getPerimetre();
        $("#prevision_form").html(html); 
    });
    ...
}
```

---

Additionally you can improve your `getPerimetre` by using the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) jquery method

```
var getPerimetre = function () {
   return $(".perimetre").map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
};
```

Comment: Problem is I want to get them after !

Comment: @Pye does the `html` returned from the ajax call contain new `.perimetre` elements ?

Comment: @pye, you need to make sure the ajax call is finished (*since it is asynchronous, so you may click the button before the ajax is complete*). updated answer..