# JQueryUI sortable only works once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I calling JQueryUI.js in a page header then loading the content with AJAX.

Jquery drag and drop works one time then quits working. If I JqueryUI.js with every AJAX content load it works, but that is extremely slow. This is in YII framework

So the whole thing looks like :

Page.php:

```
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.ui.js');
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/product.js');
```

product.js:

```
// need to namespace this to get access to jquery.ui.js sortable function
(function($) {
    SORTABLE = {
      mySortable: function(inputId) {
        $('#sortable-list-left').sortable();
        $('#sortable-list-right').sortable();
      }
     };
}(jQuery));

$(document)
  .ready(function() {
      function loadRecord(id, sku) {
      $.ajax({
        data: "id=" + id + "&sku=" + sku + "&project_id=" + urlParam("project"),
        url: "/product/ajaxGetRecord",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
          // process JSON response
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
          // update the html with the new info
          $("#productForm")
            .html(obj.form);
          (function() {
            SORTABLE.mySortable(urlParam("project"));
          })();
        }
      });
   });
```

_pagePartial.php :

```
 <div id="productForm">  
    // dynamic content filled in here
 </div>
```

This namespacing strategy works for all my other JS, but doesn't work for Jquery.ui.js ... it applies the sortable method and I am able to drag and drop one time, but then it no longer works.

The **working** option, which is not ideal, is:

_pagePartial.php :

```
   // called every single ajax update ... ugh! 
   $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.ui.js');
   $('#sortable-list-left').sortable();
   $('#sortable-list-right').sortable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't remove the list holder (such as ul), and you have dynamical li content inside it, you won't have to rebind `sortable()` after ajax call. Otherwise, you replace your list with new HTML content, you have to do it.
Here is example of [David Hoerster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237808/david-hoerster)

[Example sortable with ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/VxYmw/2/)

Comment: #sortable-list-left , #sortable-list-right are generated by ajax call, so I do need to rebind. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: "#sortable-list-left , #sortable-list-right are generated by ajax call" - It means that they are new DOM which are added, if you are looking for actually answer behind it, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-ajax-loads?answertab=active#tab-top