# Trouble with "mouseup" once DOM has been updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am writing a function that will be triggered every time I release the mouse(mouseup) from a  inside a table row. This is accomplished using jquery: `$('textarea').mouseup(function (e){ ...code });`
Everything works fine except for when I add a new row to the table. Once I add the new row, i seems that the mouseup event is not detected.
See the code in the link and do the following:
1. Write some text in the Col2 or Col3
2. Highlight the text. Expected: An alert will be shown with the text.
3. Press Add Row button, write something and highlight the text. The expected alert is not shown.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3h2atst/)

Thanks!

Comment: try to use .on('mouseup')

Comment: Please don't include links in code comments. Include the code as the warning when you entered that link told you to do. Also, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-content-is-loaded-via-ajax). Don't worry about the fact that the new HTML is loaded via AJAX; it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [delegate events in jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  How I'd write your javascript.

```
$('table').on('mouseup', 'textarea', function({
  console.log('I work!');
});
```

[Here is a working update of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3h2atst/2/)

Comment: Another question. I have a function to add more rows to the table. Once information has been entered in the textarea fields, I want to clone the table and replace every <textarea> with a <p>. The issue I now have is that the information inside every textarea is not copied.It just copies the table, not what is inside the textarea. New code to clone the masterTable: $(document).on('click','#rep',function(){
var tempTable = $('#masterTable');
var temClone = $("<div/>").append(tempTable.clone()).html();
var rep = temClone.replace("textarea","p");
$("#a").html(rep);
});Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: @Joel, can you pleas make a new question (with a jsFiddle) and post a link?  I think this comment area isn't enough space to provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `$(document).on('mouseup',selector,function(){});`

Comment: I think it's a good idea to make the event delegation as specific as possible, rather than arbitrarily binding to the `document`.  In this example, if there is another `<textarea>` somewhere else on the page (like a "contact me" form or something), a `mouseup` on it will also trigger an event that is clearly only intended for the table.  Better to use `$('table')` instead in my opinion.

Comment: i didn't read the part that said "inside a table" so you are correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
$(document).on('mouseup','textarea',function(){
});
```

This would help you.
keep coding :)