# .each with dynamically added content - jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I'm using infinite scroll made by Paul Irish which adds new content from paginator dynamically. I do get my other jquery's to work with .on method, but how to use it with .each? All I have come up with is it will fire multiple times or doesn't work at all on dynamically added items.

My code:

```
function delete() {
    $('.delete').each(function(index, value) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $(this).on("click", function() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
                $(this).parents('.feed').fadeOut();

                var suggests = $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    datatype: 'html',
                    data: "id=" + id,
                    url: 'http://localhost/delete',
                    success: function(data) {}
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Delegate from the document: `$(document).on("click", ".delete", yourEventHandlerFunction);` [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090957/2476755)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-content-is-loaded-via-ajax

Comment: What @royhowie said. Or less pretty option: `$(this).off('click').on('click')...`

Comment: no, you want the `yourEventHandlerFunction` to be the anonymous function passed to `$(this).click`. You may have to adapt the callback, though.

Comment: @royhowie if I understood correctly, adding: $(document).on("click", ".delete", delete); to fire up the function on click causes the future clicks to be fired up multiple times. For example if I delete one post and decide to delete the other one, for the other one it fires two times. And sorry, I deleted earlier message, I pressed enter accidentaly :)

Comment: Ok so thanks @royhowie and Johan for answers but with my limited skills  (quite new to jquery) I really have no idea how to start to make this. If either of you could answer with bit more details, great!

Comment: ah, actually got it to work with callback thanks to answer of @Johan using .off method. Thanks!