# Index of same name element jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have many elements with same name:

```
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][0]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][1]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][2]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][3]" />
```

I want jquery give me the index number of selector name, so if I select first one give me number (0), and so on.

I did this with jquery:

```
 var arrayname = $(this).attr('name');
 var arrayindex = arrayname.substring(24,25);
```

arrayindex return me the **Index** that I want, but I think this is not good way to do that, because maybe You have index with 2 digit number, so the substring not work fine.

Please advice ..

Comment: why don't you maintain that value in custom attribute??

Comment: You could for example use a regex to get the value of your index. Regex would be matching anything inside second `[ ]` brackets

Comment: You need to show more code that how you're using $(this) as context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this can help you：

```
...
var name = ($this).attr('name'); 
var digits = name.match(/\d+/g)
var index = digits.pop() // suppose your name has more than one digit, the last one is what you want(index) 
...
```

Answer (score 5):

> need it with Education[GraduationDate] not only Education

Try using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) with <strike>`"input[name^=Education]"`</strike>  `"input[name^=Education\\[GraduationDate\\]]"` passed as selector parameter

> ```
> .index( selector )
> ```
>
> **selector**
>
> Type: Selector
>
> A selector representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an element.

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).index("input[name^=Education\\[GraduationDate\\]]"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][0]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][1]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][2]" />
<input type="text" name="Education[GraduationDate][3]" />
```

Comment: I need it with Education[GraduationDate] not only Education

Comment: @MuhannadAlsuleimani See updated post ; note `[` , `]` requires escaping in selector string at attribute selector where no surrounding quotes present

Comment: @MuhannadAlsuleimani _"always give me -1"_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: The text element generated dynamically !

Comment: Where is `.index()` called ? Inside an `event` handler ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-content-is-loaded-via-ajax

Comment: I use arrayname.match(/\d+/g) and it's work for me !

Comment: @MuhannadAlsuleimani Is requirement to return actual index of element in relation to elements of same type ?, or return string within `[]` of `input` element `name` attribute ?

Comment: I just need the number between [ ], I think this the index of this element, because all other things to control this element depending in this number between [ ].

Comment: Tks a lot! Works fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$("[name^='Education[GraduationDate]']").index(this)
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/159/)

Comment: @MuhannadAlsuleimani So provide jsFiddle replicating your issue because obviously you are doing something wrong (or i miss something)

Comment: The code is bigger, I just trying to edit script,  
The text element generated dynamically !