# How to set active tab after fetching the view from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am trying to set `active tab` for `bootstrap 3` tabs after fetching the view from an ajax call but Its not working.

**The view is something like this:**

```
<div class="portlet light ">
    <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
        <div class="caption">
            <i class="icon-globe font-dark hide"></i>
            <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase">TODAY</span>
        </div>
        <ul id="tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#tab_1_1" class="active" data-toggle="tab"> Collections </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab"> Activities </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <!--BEGIN TABS-->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
```

**And here is the script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_page() 
{


    $.ajax(
        {
        url: 'notification_table/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        }).done(
                function(data)
                {
                $('#home_view').html(data);
                }
                );

    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab_1_2"]').tab('show');
}

 window.onload = function () 
 {
    load_page();
    setInterval(function () {
    load_page(); }, 5000);
 }
</script>
```

As you can see that I tried doing `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab_1_2"]').tab('show');` and I also tried `$('#tab a[href="#tab_1_2"]').tab('show');` but both are not working.

*What am I doing wrong here?*

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I get no error but the active class doesn't change either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `class="active"` only in `li` not in `anchor tag`, almost  everything right.

```
 <li class="active">
     <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab"> Collections </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may look for "jQuery doesn't work after the content is loaded via AJAX".
[jQuery doesn't work after content is loaded via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062899/jquery-doesnt-work-after-content-is-loaded-via-ajax)

I fixed my code before but I forget what I did.