# Can't select element after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using the WordPress theme TwentyTwelve and it seems to load pages via ajax requests.   I have a button (#header-navigation-link) that shows and hides another element on my page.  It works on the first page load without ajax calls, but when I navigate to another page ajax loads it, and my program can no longer find #nav-mobile-wrapper.

```
        $(document).on('click', "#header-navigation-link", function () {

        $(document).find("#nav-mobile-wrapper").fadeToggle();
        alert( 'Success!' );
    });
```

On all the ajax loaded pages the alert always pops up, so it's finding the button, just not the element to show and hide.   I also tried swapping the two so you click on #nav-mobile-wrapper to toggle #header-navigation-link, and the same thing happens just vise versa.

What am I missing to target #nav-mobile-wrapper in this function?

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: I'd like to know the answer, but as a workaround, you could try to load the javascript with the ajax call, then it will work. (if you can tweak wordpress to do that which I have no idea if thats possible)

Comment: This question is unclear. "I'm using the wordpress theme Twenty Twelve and it seems to load pages via ajax requests." I don't think 2012 loads any pages via ajax requests.

Comment: I agree with @JimMaguire here. Can you provide an example page? Can you confirm the JS is in each page load?

Comment: And what happens when you enter `$(document).find("#nav-mobile-wrapper").fadeToggle();` or `$("#header-navigation-link")` in the console on those pages?

Answer (score 2):

Is this element("#nav-mobile-wrapper") also generated by ajax? If so, make sure your click function and the place where this element is generated are in the same 'scope'. For example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
       // this is where you send the ajax request to server
      }).done(function(response){
       //because you said, it loaded page via ajax request, so page's loading and #nav-mobile-wrapper's generating probably happened here
       // If so, try put your click function here, inside the 'done' block!
       $(document).on('click', "#header-navigation-link", function(){
       // your stuff
     });
   })
```

I think why your function doesn't work is simply because it can't find the #nav-mobile-wrapper element. Without your code this is the best guess I can have. Anyway, let me know if you still have this problem.

BTW, I think

```
$("#header-navigation-link").on('click',function(){
// you code
});
```

is an easier way to write and read :)

Comment: Tried many ways to Select or Trigger events automatically on elements loaded by ajax and finally this was the fix for me **( Solved )** https://stackoverflow.com/a/68383274/9857162

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Id ,need not to find it again,Just select it.

```
  $(document).on('click', "#header-navigation-link", function () {    
        $("#nav-mobile-wrapper").fadeToggle();
        alert( 'Success!' );
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately I've tried this too.  Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

You are strongly discouraged from using the `load()` method. Try using [this method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) and place the element selection before the body function ends.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on SO. Please provide the essence of the solution here.